# Floated element gets outside of its parent?

Tags: css, css-float

I have an left floated div in another div and the floated divs content is getting out of the parent.

See live:

http://jsfiddle.net/eWkUg/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  width: 600px;
}
ul li {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
.img-section {
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="img-section">
      <img src="http://www.placehold.it/50X100">
    </div>
     Hello world
  </li>
  <li>
    How to avoid the red box getting out of the black one? (and hiding another list element)
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've been trying clear: left/right/both, but nothing helps.

How to avoid this? I HAVE to float the whole div (not the contents) due to image overlay (not included in example above)

Comment: do you want to limit the inner div's height or is the main div supposed to extend accordingly to the inner contents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fix it by adding [`overflow:auto`](http://jsfiddle.net/eWkUg/8/) to `ul li`, if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: I like this slightly better than Sotiris' answer because it uses 'auto' instead of 'hidden'.  Using 'hidden' can leave you unaware of other issues you might have dealing with margin, padding, width, etc..  The 'hidden' value also has its place for float containment like this, but I'd start with 'auto'.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you need, but you can add `overflow:hidden` for `ul li` this will show the image's div wrapped by the `li`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/eWkUg/9/

Comment: That's interesting. Why does `overflow: hidden` effect this?

Comment: @Tomalak this article shed light on the topic http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ and some answers in SO also :)

Comment: @Tomalak: if you think about it, the browser has to calculate the height of the element to be able to deal with any (potential) overflow.

Comment: @reisio: Couldn't that have potentially negative side-effects, like, actually *hiding* content inadvertently?

Comment: @Tomalak yes. But `overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll` have the same effect so you just choose what fits better.

Comment: @Sotiris: Isn't `overfow:auto` the default anyway? What use would explicitly setting it have?

Comment: @Tomalak the default is `visible`

Answer (score 3):

Floated elements do not expand their parent's height. This causes the effect you see.

You must add a block-level element with `clear: left;` after the last floated element:

```
<li>
    <div class="img-section"><img /></div>
    <div class="text-section">...</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</li>
```

Usually a `<br>` is used for that purpose.

Comment: `<br style="clear: left;" />` is old fashion method and non-semantic

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout to:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <div class="img-section">...</div>
       <div class="text-section">...</div>
       <br style="clear:left" /> <<---- add this 
    </li>
    etc...
```

Once you float an element, it's somewhat removed from the document flow, and you have to force the parent container to extend past the floated element's lower limit. You do that by adding that extra 
 line.

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear:both` to ul li:

```
ul li {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    margin: 15px 0;
    clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hAFWA/

Comment: Doesn't address the issue, or all of the issue.