# CSS ul li height does not cover the content

Tags: css

The li height is not defined and it automatically changes with the content. However, it only changes with the right hand side of its content rather than the left. Have changed the left side to block but it does not work. The link is as follows:
[http://ec2-52-32-145-125.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/#/posts][1]

Comment: This is pretty much exactly the same as this question: [Floated element gets outside of its parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837809/floated-element-gets-outside-of-its-parent) The left image is floated and is not contained by the parent.

Comment: Another solution is to use a [clearfix as outlined here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I will close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.posts li {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please vote to close as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837809/floated-element-gets-outside-of-its-parent) and delete this answer. This is a common problem and there is no need to keep this question around...